# How can i crop a Image in Twig Template?

Tags: templates, twig, symfony, frontend, crop

How can i build in my twig Template a Image-Crop?

I have a big Image (450x600px) and in the Frontend-Output i need a 80x80px Image.

I use symfony for the Backend and twig for the Frontend.

I hope you can Help me for a twig Image crop.

Thanks

Comment: You don't, you do this in the controller

Comment: Thanks for the fast Answer, have you a Example ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/filters/sizing.html

Comment: thanks, perfekt i use this ! :)

Answer (score 2):

As said by DarkBee, you can use LiipImagineBundle.

After installation, you will have to create a configuration for LiipImagine in your config.yml and then you will have two choices : generate image in a controller or generate it from a twig filter.

See all details and some examples here : https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle (look at section "Create Thumbnails")

If you choose to generate image from a twig filter, you will write something like this in your twig template :

```
<img src="{{ asset('/your/image/path.jpg') | imagine_filter('your_filter_name') }}" />
```

The complete documentation can be found here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/index.html (data loaders, cache resolvers, thumbnail, scale, crop, strip, rotate, watermark, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PHP and components for doing that job. For me it is better using Jquery and I found a simple plugin called [jQuery-crop](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper).

The following code would help you with this plugin:

```
 $( 'img.crop' ).crop( {
        width  : 80, 
        height : 80
    } );
```

Just need to choose image element. Hope this help you!

Comment: mh, thanks but i need a solution for twig, and which I can edit in the template.